# DynamoDB and DocumentClient giving different key values?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use aws DynamoDB and have read some guides on create, read and updating items on tables. But for some reason I am getting different key values when using documentClient and DynamoDB; namely the key values are slightly different.

In my code I have:

```
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

async function returnServers(){
    await dynamodb.scan({TableName: 'pixelbot_servers'}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("dynamodb scan succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
    });
    
    await docClient.scan({TableName: 'pixelbot_servers'}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("docClient scan succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
    });
```

However when I look at my console, I get items with different key values. The keys are the same but the values are off by a few digits.

```
docClient scan succeeded: {
  "Items": [
    {
      "server_id": 558952579627876350,
      "getrole_post_id": 797525306164510700
```

and

```
dynamodb scan succeeded: {
  "Items": [
    {
      "server_id": {
        "N": "558952579627876353"
      },
      "getrole_post_id": {
        "N": "797525306164510740"
```

I was just wondering why i'm getting different values when I am only using a single table. The values that tend to be correct are the ones coming from dynamodb instead of docClient which I see most people using.

EDIT: I have changed the data types to strings on the table, so I will get consistent results from both docclient and dynamodb, still unsure why the values were different when using datatype: number. Could be an incorrect conversion from int to bigint or something similar. Unsure.

Comment: scan doesn't guarantee the order, perhaps the order in which you are getting the records is different each time, i can't really think of any reason why each client gives a different result.

Comment: It's not the order which I am concerned about, it's the results. I don't even know where the docClients results are coming from because I only have one table with the same results as the ones dynamodb is returning.

Comment: I don't see where you are saying the keys are the same - which field is the key in your results? because both the server_id and getrole_post_id have different values.

Comment: You can see the data type limits here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes

Comment: How many items are in this table? Is it sufficiently few that they are all returned in a single scan? If not, you need to paginate as needed, aggregate results, then finally sort and compare the results.

Comment: @E.J.Brennan both values are different from each other, whereas they should both be the same.

Comment: @jarmod it says the that number datatype has a precision of 38 digits, my key values are below 38 digits so I
'm not sure why it doesn't work. Each item only has 2 keys, and I only have one item so it shouldn't vary.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Node limit. DocumentClients maps Dynamodb types to Node types, in this case N -> number. The value exceeds accuracy, so you loose that info during parsing. DocumentClient does not support such case, you need to write your own parsing for Dynamodb - > Node types

Comment: According to the aws docs, NUMBER has 38 digits of precision, but my keys are below 38 digits so I am still unsure as to why it isn't accurate. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes

Comment: Exactly, Dynamodb supports such precision but Node number don't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here appears to be a combination of Python's float implementation and boto3's choice of float to represent Number attributes.

In Python, if you initialize a variable to `558952579627876353` then print it, it has value `558952579627876353`. If, however, you initialize a variable to the float value `558952579627876353.0` and then print it, it has value `5.5895257962787635e+17` or effectively `558952579627876350`. Specifically it has lost precision after `...635` and everything remaining becomes zero.

Similarly, `797525306164510740.0` becomes `7.975253061645107e+17`, effectively `797525306164510700`.

I'd recommend (as you've done) using strings for IDs. Also see [boto/boto3/issues/665](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/665) for context.